# Uniqueness of integral curves starting on boundary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm only aware of ODE uniqueness on open subsets of $R^n$, which is useful when we want to prove uniqueness of integral curves on a smooth manifold.

Suppose we have an interal curve $f:[0,\delta]\to M$ that starts on the boundary, how can we show it is unique?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the context of your question?  What are your assumptions on the vector field?  What have you done?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @user539887 I thought this is legitimate as a stand alone question. The real context is I'm self learning Lee, and there is a problem that asks you to understand flowouts from the boundary of a manifold with a boundary. I have a good sketch of proof apart from this part I'm not sure about (I believe it's true, but not sure). The naive attempt says we take a boundary chart $A$, so that we have a smooth map $A \to R^n$ representing the vector field, so that we can extend this to a map from a nbr of $A$, but the problem is that the extension has nontrivial freedom.

Comment: If at each point of the boundary the vector field is transverse to it then integral curves are defined (at least for $t>0$ or for $t<0$, sufficiently close to $0$), and the necessity to extend the field "outside" $M$ makes no difficulty. But if the field is at some points of the boundary tangent and at others transversal, the situation becomes much more complicated. Such problems have been considered by control theory people, see [Bony–Brezis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bony%E2%80%93Brezis_theorem).

Comment: @user539887 Thanks, we may assume that at each point of the vector field it's inwardly pointing. I don't think I follow your argument; if we have two integral curves $a,b$ of a smooth inward pointing vector field $V$ starting on $p$ (a point on the boundary) that are different in arbitarily small nbr of $p$, I am not able to obtain a contradiction from the following; if we take a boundary chart $U$ of $p$, and consider an extension of $V$ to this $U$, then there is a unique integral curve passing through $p$, but it doesn't have to be either of $a,b$, who are defined on an half interval.

Comment: The integral curve starting at a point on the boundary is independent, **for $t>0$**, of an extension of the vector field.

Comment: @user539887 I don't see why that's true, but in any case that's not what bothering me. I want to understand why there is a unique integral curve that starts at $p$. If $p$ was interior the argument would go roughly as take some chart, now your two integral curves are solutions of the ODE on an open interval, so they're the same. This doesn't work here since when we go to a chart they're not defined on an open interval.

Comment: They are defined on some open interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ ($\delta > 0$ can depend on the initial point). Now take their restrictions to $[0,\delta)$, and that gives a thing called a *semiflow*.

Comment: @user539887 I think we're disagreeing on the definition of an integral curve on a vector field to a manifold with boundary. An integral curve on a vector field from a interval $J$ to $M$ is a smooth map that at each $t$ the differential goes to the appropriate vector in the vector field. In particular, if $J$ is $[0,\delta)$, it's true that if you take a boundary chart I must supply an extension of the map to say $(-\delta,\delta)$, but I have no obligation about the derivative satisfying any ODE. Do you see my problem?

Comment: The definition of the right derivative at $0$ of a function $f$ from $[0,\delta)$ to any $\mathrm{R}^n$ (any Banach space, for that matter) does not require any extension to the left of $0$: one just takes $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$.

Comment: @user539887 Correct, but for $t<0$ you can say nothing about the derivative..., so you don't know if it satisfies the ODE (Which is an arbitary extension of the vector field)

Comment: If you have an extension, the derivative at a given point at $t=0$ equals the field vector at the point (in fact, only the right derivative has relevance, the left derivative is an artifact, sort of).

Comment: @user539887 You're still ignoring that for $t<0 $we're not satisfying any ODE and there is then no uniqueness

Comment: For $t < 0$ it satisfies the ODE given by the **extension** of the vector field.  The extension can be made as regular as the original vector field, so we have uniqueness if the original field is of class $C^1$, say.

Comment: @user539887 Why does it satisfy the ODE? I'm following Lee's definitions

Comment: Sorry, I am at a loss, and not going to discuss it further.

Comment: @user539887 We're going by different definitions I think. Thanks for trying to help :)